# View Controller Pushed from other view controller never loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nib

In my tab based application, I have a View Controller with a `UITableView` that I created in storyboard. When you swipe on one of the images in the table, I'd like for the current View Controller (`SecondViewController`) to load a xib file(`SpeciesViewController.xib`) so as to "take the app" to a new view. So far, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called on swiping, but the xib file is never loaded.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SpeciesViewController* speciesController = [[[SpeciesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SpeciesViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

   // SpeciesViewController* speciesController = [[SpeciesViewController alloc] init];
    Species *theSpecies = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    speciesController.theSpecies = theSpecies;

    switch (sortBySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case kSortByCommonNameFirst:
            speciesController.title = [theSpecies commonNameFirstLast];
            break;
        case kSortByCommonNameLast:
            speciesController.title = [theSpecies commonNameLastFirst];
            break;
        case kSortByScientificName:
            speciesController.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                                       [theSpecies.scientificName substringToIndex:1],
                                       [[theSpecies.scientificName substringFromIndex:1] lowercaseString]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    speciesController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    //// Store current index path for viewDidAppear animation. ////
    self->currentSelectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:speciesController animated:YES];

}
```

The `SpeciesViewController` nib has `SpeciesViewController` as its custom class in the attributes inspector. For this reason, I would expect the ViewDidLoad, or any other method from `SpeciesViewController.m`, to be called when I `pushViewController:speciesController`.

Many posts about issues loading a nib have to do with mistakes of `initWithNibName` vs `initWithCoder`. However, I believe I am correctly using `initWithNibName` because I am doing so from a view controller.

I appreciate any help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use autorelease,this should work if nib name is correct

```
 SpeciesViewController* speciesController = [[SpeciesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SpeciesViewController" bundle:nil] ;
```

and also I think you should first embed your tableviewcontroller inside NavigationController, if you have not done it then I guess self.navigationControlller is nil currently.

You can present view controller like this

```
[self presentViewController:speciesController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Is there a way for me to load the nib from `SecondViewController` that doesn't require a navigation controller actually?

Comment: @Matt yes you can present view controller , check my updated answer, if face problem, ask